# Override Spring Starter Version version in gradle

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, gradle

I would like the maven equivalent of `properties` in gradle:

```
<properties>
        <spring-batch.version>4.0.0.M2</spring-batch.version>
</properties>
```

When I added `ext['spring-batch.version'] = '4.0.0.M2'` in `build.gradle`, imports are not working.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext['spring-batch.version'] = '4.0.0.M2'

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch')
    compile("org.hsqldb:hsqldb")
}
```

I also tried to add `spring-batch.version=4.0.0.M2` in `gradle.properties`, but not working also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's failing because `4.0.0.M2` [isn't in Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.springframework.batch%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spring-batch-core%22).

To fix it, add the Spring milestone Maven repository:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { 
        url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

first I'd use the new plugin mechanis like so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories { mavenCentral() }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application' // for docker needed the main class in jar manifest
    id 'eclipse'
    id 'idea'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '1.5.4.RELEASE' // automagically includes io.spring.dependency-management
}
```

this should automagically give you the correct version of all `org.springframework.boot` dependencies, without having to specify them explicitly (so no need to give a version number for spring-batch.

if you'd like to define further project.ext properties, do so like:

```
ext {
    group = 'minimal_cloud_stream_producer'
    groupId = 'de.demo'
    baseName = 'minimal_cloud_stream_producer'
    port = 8080
}
```

maybe you have to add a `dependencyManagement` section too, like so

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.5.4.RELEASE'
        mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Dalston.SR1'
    }
}
```

Comment: But the OP wants to specify a different version than what's specified in the 1.5.4 BOM